# Spring Boot ConfigurationProperties not loading

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

The problem is as the title says.  I can't see the issue so I need other eyes on this.  At this point i am starting to think IntelliJ is messing with me.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEncryptableProperties
public class App
{
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);


public static void main( String[] args )
{

    ApplicationContext cxt = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

   RIMService rim = cxt.getBean(RIMService.class);
```

All property classes are POJO

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "regulus")
public class RegulusProperties {

    private String soapUsername;
    private String soapPassword;
    private String repositoryName;
    private String wsdlLocation;
    private String dbServerName;
    private String databaseName;
    private String storedProcedureName;
    private String dbUsername;
    private String soapConnection;
<Getters and Setters>
```

regulusProperties is loaded below via Autowire

```
@Component
public class RIMService {
final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RIMService.class);



private RegulusProperties regulusProperties;

@Autowired
public void setRegulusProperties(RegulusProperties regulusProperties){
    this.regulusProperties = regulusProperties;
}
```

The properties are coming back as null.

```
regulus.wsdlLocation=https://ix1rglscrpt3.am.rim.com/edms/edms_ws.asmx?WSDL
regulus.soapUsername= rim_regulus_c16
regulus.soapPassword=ENC(q1xHgKzfjFkiTLY0yVPiM2KD/sGairPC)
```

Comment: is it in `application.properites` ?

Comment: Yes.  I have an application.properties and an application-dev.properties.  At this point they are identical  I made a smaller app for just the property objects and that works.  It is so odd because it was working earlier..  Now none of the @ConfigurationProperties classes are returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be IntelliJ and Maven messing with me.  Using the Maven Clean and compile, I would run the app and not have any of the @ConfigProperties load.  Just using a clean and allowing IntelliJ to compile and build (via running the app) and it would work.  Sure glad I spent all of that time chasing non-existing configuration errors.